# nuxt-i18n загрузка списка локалей

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, i18n, nuxt.js

В приложении используется nuxt-i18n https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/ .
Список локалей задается в конфиге nuxt:

```
 {
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: ['en', 'fr', 'es'],
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      vueI18n: {
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        messages: {
          en: {
            welcome: 'Welcome'
          },
          fr: {
            welcome: 'Bienvenue'
          },
          es: {
            welcome: 'Bienvenido'
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Как можно указать список локалей запросив его по api ?